# File modification time gets overwritten by background cache flushing

Tags: c++, winapi

I have code that performs following steps:

1. open file
2. write data
3. set file timestamps (via `SetFileInformationByHandle(FileBasicInfo)`)
4. close file

When file is stored on certain NAS devices (and accessed via share) it's modification time ends up being set to current time.

According to Process Monitor `Close()` in step 4 results in a `Write` (local cache gets flushed/pushed to NAS device) that (seemingly) updates file's mtime on server.

If I add `FlushFileBuffers()` (or sleep for few seconds) between steps 2 and 3 -- everything is fine.

Is this a bug in SMB implementation of this NAS device (Dell EMC Isilon) or `SetFileInformationByHandle()` never promised anything?

What is the best way to deal with this situation? I would really like to avoid having to call `FlushFileBuffers()`...

**Edit:** Great... :-/ It looks like for executables (and **only** executables) `atime` (last access time) gets screwed up too (in the same way). Only these are harder to reproduce -- need to run this logic few times. Could be some antivirus... I am still investigating.

**Edit 2:** According to `procmon` access time gets updated by `EXPLORER.EXE` -- when it sees an executable, it can't resist opening it and reading portions of it (probably extracting the icon).

Comment: Do you want to set `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING/FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH`? See `CreateFile` > [Caching Behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea#caching-behavior)

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT I thought about it, but 1. it puts restrictions on read/write size/alignment. 2. I don't know what else can happen under the hood -- what it I set access time in step 3 and in `Close()` OS does smth that updates it? There is nothing in MSDN wrt guarantees provided by `Close()` or `SetFileInformationByHandle()`

Comment: The behavior of file caching is by design, the `WriteFile` and `WriteFileEx` functions write data to an internal buffer that the **operating system writes to a disk or communication pipe on a regular basis.** The `FlushFileBuffers` function writes all the buffered information for a specified file to the device or pipe.

Comment: For read/write size/alignment, you could refer to [File Buffering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-buffering#alignment-and-file-access-requirements)

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT I know all this... Problem is unexpected mtime updates that overwrite value set explicitly using same handle. I can't figure out if this this a bug in Isilon or I am not supposed to mix writes and mtime updates on the same handle. Bottomline, now my code flushes file buffers before setting mtime and it is not ideal...

Comment: Maybe you could try crt function [`_utime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/utime-utime32-utime64-wutime-wutime32-wutime64?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=msvc-160) to modify mtime, follow step 1,2,4,`_utime`.

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT `_utime()` is a function from CRT and is implemented on top of Win32. I don't see how it will help here or how this can be related to the topic...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really do anything -- I guess Isilon's SMB implementation doesn't support certain things (that would've preserved timestamps).

I simply added `FlushFileBuffers()` before `SetFileInformationByHandle()` and made sure there are no related race conditions in my code.